# How do I implement pytest for a function with @contextlib.contextmanager?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

How do I implement pytest for a function with `@contextlib.contextmanager` ?

In order to improve the coverage, I want to have a test for this function as well.

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def working_directory_relative_to_script_location(path):
    """Changes working directory, and returns to previous on exit. It's needed for PRAW for example,
    because it looks for praw.ini in Path.cwd(), but I have that file in the settings directory.

    """
    prev_cwd = Path.cwd()
    script_dir = Path(os.path.realpath(__file__)).parent
    os.chdir(script_dir / path)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(prev_cwd)
```

Comment: what about filling a test using it?

Comment: use fixtures as described in pytest docs

Comment: @aws_apprentice I had a look through https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html, I still don't know how to do it. :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the nicest solution because it actually creates directories on your drive:

```
import contextlib
import os
from pathlib import Path

@contextlib.contextmanager
def working_directory_relative_to_script_location(path):
    """Changes working directory, and returns to previous on exit. 
    It's needed for PRAW for example,
    because it looks for praw.ini in Path.cwd(), 
    but I have that file in the settings directory."""
    prev_cwd = Path.cwd()
    script_dir = Path(os.path.realpath(__file__)).parent
    os.chdir(script_dir / path)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(prev_cwd)


def test_decorator():
    tmp = 'tmp_dir'
    initial_path = Path.cwd()
    os.mkdir(tmp)
    tmp_path = os.path.join(initial_path, tmp)

    @working_directory_relative_to_script_location(tmp_path)
    def with_decorator():
        return Path.cwd()

    try:
        assert with_decorator() == tmp_path
        assert Path.cwd() == initial_path
    except AssertionError as e:
        raise e
    finally:
        os.rmdir(tmp)

test_decorator()
```

Here, I created a function that returns the current working directory and decorated it with your context manager. What one would expect from your context manager is that it changes the directory to `tmp` during the function invocation (this is tested by the first `assert` statement) and that it changes it back to the initial directory afterwards (this is tested by the second `assert` statement).

Comment: Thank you! It seems that pytest can provide a unique temporary directory with tmpdir arg, and also I was importing Path from already, therefore I changed your code to: https://pastebin.com/uWTiLEHR

It's fine, right?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest version:

```
def test_working_directory_relative_to_script_location(tmpdir):
    initial_path = Path.cwd()

    @working_directory_relative_to_script_location(tmpdir)
    def with_decorator():
        return Path.cwd()

    try:
        assert with_decorator() == tmpdir
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not strictly solve the title of the question but it offers a better solution for the typical problem it addresses.

## Use fixtures to prepare your test context.

You can easily change to a directory in a test context creating a fixture.

```py
@fixture(scope="module", autouse=True, params=["./settings"])
def in_settings_folder(request.param):
    prevdir = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(request.param)
    yield
    os.chdir(prevdir)

def test_settings_1(): # This pass
    print(f"{os.getcwd()}") # /.../project/settings
    assert check_settings()

def test_settings_2(): # This fails
    print(f"{os.getcwd()}") # /.../project/settings
    raise Exception

def test_settings_3(): # This pass
    print(f"{os.getcwd()}") # /.../project/settings
    assert check_settings()
```

I changed it a bit to use tmpdir, but you will see something like:

```sh
$ pytest -s tests/test_tests.py 
...
tests/test_tests.py /tmp/pytest-of-borja/pytest-52/settings
./tmp/pytest-of-borja/pytest-52/settings
F/tmp/pytest-of-borja/pytest-52/settings
.
...
```

Where you can see on the 3 tests, even if 1 failed, the `cwd` is maintained.

## Control the scope of your fixture

You can decide when this directory "switch" will happen using the fixture `scope`. Note if you use `autouse` with `session` all the tests will run in that directory.

You can use `scope=module` if you want to apply it to all tests in the module where it is called or `scope=class` inside a `Class` to limit it to the test inside the class:

```py
class TestSettings:
    @fixture(scope="class", autouse=True, params=["./settigns"])
    def in_settings_folder(self, tmpdir):
        prevdir = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(tmpdir)
        yield
        os.chdir(prevdir)

    def test_settings_1(self): 
        print(f"{os.getcwd()}")  # /.../project/settings
        assert check_settings()

def test_settings_2():           # /.../project
    print(f"{os.getcwd()}")
    assert check_settings()
```

## Use pytest temp folders to operate data

If your fixtures are generating data which you want to check on the tests, then use `tmpdir_factory` to create a working directory.

```py
@fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def tmpdir(tmpdir_factory):
    return tmpdir_factory.mktemp("settings")


class TestSettings:
    @fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
    def in_settings_folder(self, tmpdir):
        prevdir = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(tmpdir)
        yield
        os.chdir(prevdir)

    def test_settings(self):
        print(f"{os.getcwd()}") # /tmp/pytest-of-x/pytest-1/settings0
        assert check_settings()
```